# Adding post thumbnail in programatically inserted post

Tags: wp-insert-post

I want to insert post programatically so here is the code to add one:

```
global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'My New Post',
    'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

How to add a featured image to post and trigger it for testing ?

Comment: What do you mean by *trigger it for testing*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The post thumbnail is just saved as post meta with the key:  `_thumbnail_id`.  So after you insert the post and get the post id, you can set the post meta for that post.  The `$thumbnail_id` is just the ID of the image you'd like to set as the thumbnail, up to you since I can't tell from your question what this should be.

```
global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'My New Post',
    'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

if( ! is_wp_error( $post_id ) )
       update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id );
```

Comment: How can I test this code? If making it a function, then where should I call it?

Comment: I don't know. My point was to just let you know that you could update the post meta after however you are inserting the post.

Comment: Post thumbnail function will automatically find any meta data having image!

Comment: That's not what you asked. You asked how to programmatically set a post thumbnail when inserting a post.  You do that by setting the `_thumbnail_id` meta key for that post.  If that's not what you meant, then please revise your question for clarity.

Comment: Then what's the use of update_post_meta function, if post thumbnail function couldn't retrieve image from it!

Comment: Huh? The `_thumbnail_id` meta key is exactly what the `the_post_thumbnail()` function uses to retrieve the ID of the thumbnail. You can verify this in `wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php`

Comment: Thanks Helga, this was what I was saying in previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

use the function [`set_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail/),

```
//$file is the path to your uploaded file (for example as set in the $_FILE posted file array)
//$filename is the name of the file
//first we need to upload the file into the wp upload folder. 
$upload_file = wp_upload_bits($filename, null, @file_get_contents($file));
if(!$upload_file['error']) {
  //if succesfull insert the new file into the media library (create a new attachment post type)
  $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
  $attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_parent' => $post_id,
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
  );
  //wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );
  $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_file['file'], $post_id );
  if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
     //if attachment post was successfully created, insert it as a thumbnail to the post $post_id
     require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
     //wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $file ); for images
     $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $upload_file['file'] );
     wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attachment_data );
     set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
  $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $attachment = array(
     'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
     'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
     'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
     'post_content' => '',
     'post_status' => 'inherit'
  );
  $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );     
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
  $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

For more information see this link
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/

Comment: this will only upload a file into the media library and attach it to the post, however it will not actually update the thumbnail of the post.